# SCTP server has an abnormal behaviour when connecting with a client

Tags: linux, python-3.x, server, sctp

I have this code on a small server that is getting requests from a client using SCTP connection, I keep getting this error every now and then.

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I know that I can avoid it by using Try-except but I wanna have a deep understanding of the issue. any help?

my code is here. this is the server

```
server = ('', 29168)
sk = sctpsocket_tcp(socket.AF_INET)
sk.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sk.bindx([server])
sk.listen(5)
connection, addr = sk.accept()
while c:
      a,b,c,d = connection.sctp_recv(1024)
      print(c)
```

Comment: Your server is single-threaded, so it is stuck with the first client until it disconnects.  If you try to connect from two separate clients, you need a forking or threaded server, or an async architecture (each client gets a callback which the server loop services in between handling other clients and other tasks).

Comment: @tripleee if I make my server multi-threaded, I won't see this error anymore ?

Comment: If I were certain that this is the problem, I would have posted this as an actual answer.  There is a large number of things which could be going wrong, but I thought this was useful speculation.

Comment: @tripleee Okay thanks mate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going again through the SCTP library, I found a closed issue on Github with the [solution](https://github.com/philpraxis/pysctp/issues/19)